# python subprocess call

Tags: python

The following is a python code using the subprocess module. Can someone explain what the code is doing?

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['aspell', 'list'],
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,  # reading from the op of a pipe.
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE) # writing to the i/p of a pipe

(result, stderrdata) = process.communicate(" ".join(text))
```

Comment: Whose comments are those in the middle two lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a really badly laid out script for opening the process aspell giving it the argument list. then piping the stdout and stderr into a tuple while feeding ' '.join(text) as stdin to the process.

Comment: but can u just explain the process of popen